# WPF Datagrid isReadOnly = True, makes the checkboxcolumn disabled

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

WPF Datagrid isReadOnly = True, makes the checkboxcolumn disabled even if I set isReadOnly = false on DatagridCheckboxColumn.

How to enable the checkbox column?

Comment: question is how to enable the checkboxColumn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own DataGridTemplateColumn with a CheckBox which won't use the IsReadOnly property:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I ended up building a whole new column type which does this (and other behavior too), and it works great!  I can hook the new checkbox in the GenerateElement call.  I did have to manually set the bindings for it, since GridTemplateColumn doesn't derive from GridBoundColumn, but, it's a small price to pay.

Answer (score 2):

You can not set the DataGrid IsReadOnly but in columns.

Sample:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="SL" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" IsReadOnly="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You can create a style for columns specified in the resource and set the DataGrid to not have to keep putting in all the columns IsReadOnly

Daniel Freire - Brazil 
Response translated from Portuguese into English on google

Comment: but then how do i stop user from adding a row at the botton?

Comment: Set the property "CanUserAddRows" to false in the DataGrid